# kotlin syntax with Deferred

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

My objective is get an output that conforms to this signature `Deferred<HashMap<Long, String>?>` or maybe something better like `Job` etc. not sure what the standard way of doing thing in kotlin as well how to call/consume the function, is as I'm new to this.

Following is a draft what I'm working with in the model layer. I'd appreciate if someone can show me the right way of doing async things.

```
fun findAll(): Deferred<HashMap<Long, String>?> {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        async {
            var roles: HashMap<Long, String>? = null
            connection.readableDatabase.query("role", null, null, null, null, null, null).use { cursor ->
                if (cursor.count > 0) roles = HashMap()
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    roles?.put(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")))
                }
            }
            return roles
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would not use GlobalScope because it "lives" app lifecycle time and it's not cleared until app is killed. Therefore, you can use MVVM pattern and in viewModel use viewModelScope and launch coroutine with default dispatcher. In your
ViewModel something like:

```
 fun loadQuestions(type: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            questionsUseCase.invoke(type).fold(::handleError, ::handleUsersResponse)
        }
    }

 override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelScope.cancel()
    }
```

In short, you put business logic in ViewModel, call that function from ui(activity,fragment).This invoke function is a suspend function and you can use it instead of Deferred!

You can read it more on: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-i-getting-the-background-3e0e54d20bb

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it to use `withContext` with `async` builder. `GlobalScope` is not recommended to use. `async` will return you a `Deferred<HashMap<Long, String>?>` while you are only interested in the data . `async` is useful in case you are making multiple background calls in parallel i don't see `async` is useful in your case. So basically what you can do is make `findAll` a suspend function and call it from a scope and directly return the data you are interested in.

```
suspend fun findAll(): HashMap<Long, String>? {
     return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            var roles: HashMap<Long, String>? = null
            connection.readableDatabase.query("role", null, null, null, null, null, null).use { cursor ->
                if (cursor.count > 0) roles = HashMap()
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    roles?.put(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")))
                }
            }
         roles
     }
}
```

now you can call it from a `CoroutineScope`.  In case you are on MVVM you can use`viewModelScope` inside `ViewModel`

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
    val data = repo.findAll()
}
```

if not then you can create a Custom Ui Scope and call it directly from scope.

```
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
fun getData(){
   uiScope.launch {
       val data = repo.findAll()
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, side question, can I call a suspend func on the main thread, I assume it will not block the UI thread?

Comment: You can call  suspend from any thread what matters is is the `Dispatchers` as you see above the `suspend fun findAll()` itself getting called on `Dispatchers.IO` so you can directly call from a `Scope` . You can also set the dispatcher to `launch` builder if required like `launch(Dispatchers.IO)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate. Can you please also attempt this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948153/gracefully-handling-errors-from-suspend-functions as both are related.