# Kotlin coroutines - gracefully handling errors from suspend functions

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, try-catch, kotlin-coroutines

Trying to implement graceful handling of the errors with suspend functions that are called from async methods, How to catch the error thrown by a suspend method.

```
suspend fun findById(id: Long): User? {
    throw Exception("my exception") // intentionally throwing to simulate error situation.
    return userModel.findById(id) // IO, may throw an error
}
```

Caller piece, launching with IO thread

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {

        var userAsync: Deferred<User?>? = null
        arguments?.getLong("id")?.let {
            userAsync = async { viewModel?.findById(it) } // async for efficiency as i've other async methods too.
        }

        val data = userAsync?.await()

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            user = data // data binding, populating UI fields of user
        }
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { fault(exception) }
    }
}
```

fault method

```
private fun fault(exception: Exception) {
    Log.d("User", "fault: ${exception.localizedMessage}") // expecting output
}
```

Currently runtime is crashing, want to implement graceful handling of errors.

---

**Attempt 2**

Tried placing try catch within the async block but it didn't like it.

```
var userAsync: Deferred<UserVO?>? = null
arguments?.getLong("id")?.let {
    userAsync = async {
        try {
            delegate?.findById(it)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            print(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use a `CoroutineExceptionHandler` to make your coroutines fail gracefully:

**1) Define the handler:**

```kotlin
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, error ->
    // Do what you want with the error
    Log.d(TAG, error)
}
```

**2) Refactor your findById function to be executed within an IO context and make your ui code main safe:**

```kotlin
suspend fun findById(id : Int) : User? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    when(id){
        0 -> throw Exception("not valid")
        else -> return@withContext User(id)
    }
}
```

3. Launch your job within `MainScope` (and so update the ui), passing exceptionHandler to launch coroutine builder in order to catch the exception:

```kotlin
val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, error ->
     // Do what you want with the error
    Log.d(TAG, error)
}

MainScope().launch(exceptionHandler) {
     val user = delegate?.findById(userId)
        user?.let {
            Timber.v(it.toString())
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. can exceptionHandler be a method on a class? how will it be?

Comment: Also is `MainScope().launch` an async execution? i.e. control will not wait and go on executing the next statement? Please confirm.

Comment: MainScope().launch launches the execution of the coroutine, since findById is a suspending function the coroutine stops waiting for findById returning a result.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I want the best of both worlds, to be able to launch `async`, maybe launch a second `async` as it continues, wait on both of them while be able to handle errors gracefully. I had async wrapping the suspend function. If there's a better way I can change my strategy altogether, looking for a solid recipe.

Comment: Hi Nicola, thanks this was helpful. By the way I noticed that `MainScope()` is lifecycle aware, I put some `delay` in suspend functions and hit cancel on the fragment to get rid of it while request was in flight. the fragment destroyed and upon request return application didn't crash. so I assume. any insights you can add?

Comment: @AppDeveloper MainScope has a supervisor job in its ContextScope constructor, this way when coroutine scope is cancelled the cancellation is passed to supervisor job and doesn't affect other childs. Thanks to supervisor job the coroutine fails gracefully and your app doesn't crash even if you don't manually catch the exception.

Comment: From answer, point #2, what will be equivalent of it while using Room library? `suspend fun findById(id : Int) : User? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ // sqlite api }`, see my answer please